# How to get output from a subprocess command as a list in python?

Tags: python, perforce

I am trying to retrieve few information regarding my perforce client using python script. I only want to fetch information related to server address, cleint root etc. as follows:

```
ping_string = subprocess.Popen(['p4', 'info','ls'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE ).communicate()[0]
print ping_string
```

So i get output as:

```
User name: hello
Client name: My_machine
Client host: XYZ
Current directory: c:\
Peer address: 1.2...
Client address: 1.102....
Server address: abcd
Server root: D:\scc\data
```

But as i want to retrieve server address, client address etc so, for that i want output to be in form of a list. So, please suggest how can i get the output as list type.

Answer (score 2):

Using [`check_output`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) simplifies getting the command output, so you could do:

```
out = subprocess.check_output(cmd)

lines = out.splitlines()
```

Note that each line will contain the trailing new line character.

Or if you want the data after the colons:

```
lines = [l.split(':', 1)[1].strip() for l in out.splitlines() 
         if ':' in l]
```

`l.split(':', 1)[1]` is taking the whatever is after the colon.
`.strip()` removes the surrounding whitespaces.
`if ':' in l` is a protection against lines that don't contain a colon.